# Integrate Azure Key Vault in .NET Web API application using Secret URL

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to implement Azure Key Vault in .NET Web API app.
Can anyone let me know if I can use Secret Uri directly in appsettings.json.
Please find the image.[Key vault Uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoSOn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the secret URI method only works in Azure settings.
To use them within your application's configuration file, you would need to manually resolve the secrets in your code with the Key Vault SDK.